# "Invalid object name 'dbo.Memberships'." when trying to add new user

Tags: c#, membership-provider

I have done something in the last day or 2 to break my application.

I have a method to create a new user within a membership database using the membership provider.

e.g.

```
 public void Create(Consumer consumer)
    {

        MembershipCreateStatus status;
        if (consumer.UserId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            consumer.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        if (consumer.ConsumerId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            consumer.ConsumerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        try
        {
            var membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(consumer.UserName, consumer.Password, consumer.Email, null, null, consumer.IsApproved, consumer.UserId, out status);
....
}
```

The inner exception is

> {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Memberships'."}

Stack trace is

> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>      at System.Web.Providers.QueryHelper.GetMembership(MembershipEntities ctx, String applicationName, Guid userId)
>      at System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.Membership_CreateUser(String applicationName, String userName, String password, String salt, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, DateTime& createDate, Boolean uniqueEmail, Int32 passwordFormat, Object& providerUserKey)
>      at System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
>      at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
>      at Plenfy.Api.Models.ConsumerRepository.Create(Consumer consumer) in c:\@Code\Customers\Api\Repository\ConsumerRepository.cs:line 121

I have no clue how to fix the problem. The database and connection string looks fine and I can connect to it with EF.

Can anyone suggest how to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: When you say "you can connect to it with EF", what do you mean? You mean you can copy a connection string you see in your web.config and create a new connection to it? Or you can get a list of users back using Membership.GetUser?

What is the default membership provider in your config? Perhaps putting your config in this post (without username/passwords etc) would be a good start.

Comment: is your membership provider pointing to the right connection string?. 
EF and membership provider are separate can use different connection strings and pointing to different dbs.

Comment: As I remember the name of the table in db is dbo.webpages_Membership; Check whats happen that entity framework wants to found dbo.membership?

Answer (score -1):

```
try to use 
MembershipCreateStatus status;
        if (consumer.UserId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            consumer.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        if (consumer.ConsumerId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            consumer.ConsumerId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        try
        {
            var membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(consumer.UserName, consumer.Password, consumer.Email, null, null, consumer.IsApproved, consumer.UserId, out status);
        }
```